# Is it possible to combine two different android sdks to one?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I have Eclipse and android studio in my PC. For Eclipse and android studio i am using same sdk.

But today i have updated my android studio to 1.0 beta and by mistake i have select wrong configuration for the android studio, that's why it has download new sdk to another location.

Now, I have two android sdk at different location.
One at **C:/some_directory/sdk** (Which have new packages)
and another at **D:/some_directory/android_sdk** (which have old packages)

Now, both have different packages downloaded. I don't want to download it again. So what i want is, i want to copy the new sdk contain to old one to get all packages in one place (Old place). So, is it possible to do that? or i must have to update old packages to get it effected by new packages?

Please let me know for this thing so that i can update my old sdk and start work on same.

Comment: You can have multiple platform definitions in an sdk installation, but I suspect only one SDK tools installation.  If you have things like IDE plugins which depend on a particular tools version that may cause problems.  On a unix-style host you could probably have distinct folders and symlink the platform subfolders to a shared one, but not sure if that will work on windows and probably not worth attempting unless you are on a system with extremely constrained storage that would be expensive to upgrade (unopenable laptop?)

Comment: hummm. Thanks for reply. What i want is, I have all the packages in older sdk (sdk that is before updating studio), and it is with all required plugins. Now i have new sdk with all new packages. So can i directly copy and paste that new sdk on old sdk? Will it effect to my existing project?

Comment: @ChrisStratton can i simple copy paste both sdk to each other to get one sdk with all required tools in sdk?

Comment: That depends on which tools versions are required.  Often an android plugin to an SDK is tied to a particular version (or range) of the "sdk tools" part of the sdk.  Since there's only one folder for that, your unified SDK probably won't be able to work with two plugins of substantially different generation.

Answer (score 0):

Before do anything it's safe to keep backup copy of both sdk..

After that.. 
in **OLD_SDK** directory copy content from **NEW_SDK** directory 
and now use this "**OLD_SDK**" path in both version..

Yes you can do it like this..  Hope it helps..

Comment: 'Hope it works" is not an answer to the question which was asked

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia have you try like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set SDK location in Android Studio:

Project Structure -> SDK Location -> Choose your SDK folder

And in Eclipse:

Window -> Preferences -> Android -> SDK Location

Comment: The question was not how to set the SDK location, but rather if it is  possible to **combine** two SDK's, and you have not answered that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ok, the answer on your question is "No". You can point SDK links from Eclipse and Android Studio to one same location - in this case you will have same SDK for both IDEs. You can try "merge" your 2 SDKs by creating new SDK directory and copy-pasting all from those 2 SDKs and then use this new "merged" folder as SDK for both IDEs